# Can i generate DDL for procedure in db2?

Tags: db2

I want to check one procedure where it is being called ?
 Is there any way for his ?

i have tried to generate using db2look but it didnt work .

Comment: M Gade,
I can't quite tell what you're asking. Which platform/version are you on? (e.g. ISeries, Linux, etc.). Are you trying to determine what program is calling the stored procedure, or do you know the name of the stored proc and are trying to look at the text of it?

Comment: I am using Linux . I have created one procedure long back with name SASDBADF.ADFQ_11111_SENSITIVE_PARTA_R032, now i am trying find where it is being called ? Is there any way to find that ?

Comment: Basically what I hear is that you are uncertain if this process is called by another stored proc or by an executable.  Start with db2 first by looking at a SYSCAT.ROUTINEDEP and SYSCAT.ROUTINES equijoin. You're looking for dependencies. Look for the table name(s) your stored proc uses--it may help trigger other familiar processes connecting to it.

Comment: If your stored proc is running during a specific time, work with your linux admin to capture information about the active pids that are executing, then capture which pids are still executing after. If you don't know when its running--then rename the stored proc and let the process fail, so you'll have a trail to trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sqlpltrc and the SQL profiler utilities. There are few articles about that, but they can help to have stack call of your procedures.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/tracing?lang=en
http://angocadb2.blogspot.com.co/2014/02/tracing-log4db2-with-sqlpltrc.html

Another way to that, is to look in the TEXT column of the SYSCAT.PROCEDURES view, looking for the name of your procedures. However, if there is dynamic SQL, this could eventually not help. Also, if any function or trigger calls you SP, you need to look for the name in the corresponding tables.